# Using DISTINCT with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using  ActiveRecord / RoR.

My table looks like this:

```
id (int), start_time(time), end_time(time), ...

1, 20:00, 23:00

2, 20:00, 23:00

3, 16:00, 20:00

4, 16:00, 23:00

5, 20:00, 22:00

6, 16:00, 20:00
```

I need to return the records that have a combination distinct `start_time` + `end_time` combination.

Comment: Well, you won't be returning the records, you'll be returning a set of distinct combinations, right?  Once there is no id and it's no longer unique, it's not a record anymore.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
YourModelClass.select("DISTINCT start_time, end_time")
```

This will return objects that aren't strictly records but they will inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and you can do pretty much anything with those objects that doesn't write to the database.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields